# applying v-model results in "Failed to compile"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following, dynamically generated markup:

```
<table name="addRecordTable">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td v-for="(value, name) in insertionMenu">
            {{name}}
          </td>
          <td name="dummyForOpticalPurposes"></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <td v-for="field in insertionMenu">
          <input v-model="field" type="text"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button v-on:click="tester">Add</button>
        </td>
      </tbody>

    </table>
```

`insertionMenu` is defined in my `data()` and filled in a `created()` hook.
After being filled, the data inside `insertionMenu` looks like this:

```
{
  'Internal_key' : 0,
  'description_itc' : 1,
  'description_sysops' : 2,
}
```

The result on my MyList.vue looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHypU.jpg

I want to have the `insertionMenu` properties bound to each of these inputfields. When hitting the `ADD` button, the `insertionMenu` shall be used as payload for an AJAX request to backend. 
To accomplish this binding, I wanted to use v-model, as you can see in my markup above. 
However, using v-model like this, I get an "Failed to compile" error by vue.js. What am I missing?

Comment: can you create a pen or fiddle to play around with it

Comment: What is the `data structure` of `insertionMenu`, is it `key-value pair object` where the key is Internal_key & value 0 or an `array` of string where 0 index has value:  Internal_key

Comment: @Shivam Singh The latter, namedKey.

Comment: sorry I am still confused, is it [1] -> `{ Internal_key: 0, ... }` or [2] -> `['Internal_key', ...]` or [3] -> `{ 0: 'Internal_key', .. }`

Comment: @ShivamSingh Sry my arrow-syntax was both confusing and wrong ^^ yeah, it is the first option :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You are binding v-model directly to a v-for iteration alias. This will
>   not be able to modify the v-for source array because writing to the
>   alias is like modifying a function local variable. Consider using an
>   array of objects and use v-model on an object property instead.

Either you will have to update ds for insertionMenu as said above or change the way you are modifying insertionMenu,

[A] To change the way you are modifying `insertionMenu`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    insertionMenu: {
      'Internal_key' : 0,
      'description_itc' : 1,
      'description_sysops' : 2,
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    // [3] add a handler for oninput, this will get trigger when user gives / types an input in the input
    handleInput (evt, key) {
     // [4] modify data property: `insertionMenu` here
     this.$set(this.insertionMenu, key, evt.target.value)
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <div
    v-for="(field, key, index) in insertionMenu"
    :key="index"
  >
    {{ field }} <!-- Render to check if its modifying state -->
    <!-- [1] remove two way data-binding ie. v-model -->
    <!-- [2] attach oninput event to the input -->
    <input 
     @input="handleInput($event, key)" 
     type="text"
    />
  </div>

<div>
```

[B] Or change ds:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    insertionMenu: {
      'Internal_key' : { value: 1 },
      'description_itc' : { value: 2 },
      'description_sysops' : { value: 3 },
    }
  }
})

//
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <div
    v-for="(field, key, index) in insertionMenu"
    :key="index"
  >
    {{ field.value }} <!-- Render to check if its modifying state -->
    <input 
     type="text"
     v-model="field.value"
    />
  </div>

<div>
```

Comment: Your first approach works like a charm and fits easily into my project! THanks a lot! :)

Comment: Could you explain to me why the "$" is needed in @input="handleInput($event, key)" ?

Comment: Sometimes we need to access the original DOM event in an inline statement handler to pass it into a method, $event help us access it in the Vue's virtual dom / <template/>